# Error running a simple sql command

Tags: sql

I am very tired and maybe I am missing something obvious.

I got this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Running this simple command

```
create table tempPosition select * from Position;
```

Any idea?

Thanks

P.S. sql server 2008

**EDIT**

my apologies I forgot a fundamental piece of information, the table has an primary key that auto-generate the id. It was that column that was causing the problem. Using the full list of columns (omitting the primary key) solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [How to keep being productive when you are tired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364056/how-to-keep-being-productive-when-you-are-tired/1364074#1364074)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   Select * Into TempPosition
   From Position
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a temporary table (good for the life of your connection, then deleted when you disconnect) containing all the contents of Position.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tempPosition
FROM Position
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tempPosition as select * from Position;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server the format of the queries are as follows:

```
-- Insert And Create Table
SELECT [list items] INTO TableOut FROM TableIn

-- Create The Table Only
SELECT [list items] INTO TableOut FROM TableIn WHERE 0=1
```